# How to fit table on page in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have the following table:

[image]

As you can see, the table extends beyond the page. Is there any way to easily make it fit in the page?

Comment: Turn on the Ruler from the View tab on the ribbon bar, and click in the cell. You should be able to slide the marker to the left for the edge of the table. Also, when you click in the cell you should see a white box to the right which is the corner of the table. You can grab that. Oh, 3rd option would be to change the page to Landscape, move the column width back then change it back to portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select your table
2. Right-click, select Autofit, then select either `AutoFit to Contents` or `Autofit to Window`

The table will fit within the page.